# Jquery mobile and paypal integration

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, paypal

I've been trying to build a fairly simple phone-friendly web page that uses Paypal to complete payments.  I got the solution running with a basic HTML form and a sample PHP Express Checkout, which was working fine until I started trying to use jquery mobile to make the page phone-friendly.  I since tried another PHP library with the same result.  The library I'm now using is from Angell EYE and I've created the following basic page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dummy App</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <form method="get" action="paypal/SetExpressCheckout.php">
        <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <label for="qty">Quantity</label><input type="text" name="qty" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="4.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1.40" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Angell EYE library is located in a subdirectory called 'paypal' and after putting some dummy data into the form and clicking submit, I'm eventually directed to Paypal's Sandbox checkout and after completing the purchase I get back to the dummy site.

I then add in jquery as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dummy App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-    1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form method="get" action="paypal/SetExpressCheckout.php">
        <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <label for="qty">Quantity</label><input type="text" name="qty" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="4.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1.40" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point if I load the page and submit in Chrome, there's a wait of approx 6 seconds until the browser reports "Error Loading Page" and if I look in the Chrome console I see the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=EC-81C31424M3017780Y. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dummy.company.com' is therefore not allowed access.

If I remove the "" line from the page I no longer get the error, but I also (obviously) lose the phone optimisation...

There are lots of articles here explaining how to set HTTP headers on your server to avoid the problem; however in this case the resource is Paypal and I've found no mentioned of how/whether Paypal supports it...

Ultimately I want to build a PHP layer on my site that does some stuff and then submits initates the checkout process and I want to format the front page and had hoped to do it more easily with jqm.

I may be missing something really obvious.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: I built an Express Checkout solution on jQuery Mobile a few years back and it worked just fine.  I'll have to dig that up and I can provide samples.  [Contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) for that.  It sounds like you have the library working for you, which is interesting because you're using method GET instead of POST and my library looks for $_POST.  The PHP scripts should be completely separate from any of the jQuery stuff.  Just POST data to a PHP processor that handles the PayPal stuff, and the jQuery Mobile pages would be very simple with no PHP involved at all.